# NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription rejection but not using it

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

First time, I have a problem that is actually frustrating. I do NOT use any access to photo library, I am not saving any images in my app, I do not use any of the API requiring usage description, I do not use any other library in my project, but when I upload my app, it is rejected with `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key missing. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are you using any third party frameworks ?

Comment: I see that AssestsLibrary.frameowrk is linked but never used, I think that's the case

Comment: better to remove AssestsLibrary.frameowrk

Answer (score 0):

You are not using it, but some library that you are using is. In my case it was a library that allowed users to connect to our support team, and among other things that library allowed the user to send screen shots with problems to the support team. And screen shots are in the photo library.

You should find out which of your library uses this, and either remove it, or add a line in your info.plist that explains the usage. Users will not see this until you actually do access the photo library. Which may be never.

Comment: I have seen now that in my app, I am linking AssestsLibrary.framework, but I am not using it, that could be it?

Comment: I am not using anywhere any library that contains some photo manipulation, I am just opening my camera not to record or to take photos. Just opening it and it asks me for that key